# Why I cannot do 'cout << 3*" ";'?

Tags: c++

Why I cannot do

```
cout << 3*" ";
```

Error:

```
E:\C++\test\main.cpp|12|error: invalid operands of types 'int.' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator*'
```

Comment: Why should you be able to? By default there is no operator* which takes a number and a string, and does what you want. Do you have a context or Framework where this should be possible? Or is it plain C++ without extensions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Just a tip: Try to get more familiar to compiler output, `invalid operands of types 'int.' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator*'` answers your question if you read it carefully =)

Comment: std::cout << std::setw(5) << "";

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some languages allow the multiplication operator to be used in this way. For instance Python allows you to write:

```
3*" "
```

and evaluates that as

```
"   "
```

But C++ does not allow this use of the multiplication operator. Which is precisely what the compilation error is telling you.

You are attempting to create a string that contains three spaces. Do this, for example, by using the fill constructor of the standard string class:

```
std::string(3, ' ')
```

And to send that to `cout`:

```
std::cout << std::string(3, ' ');
```

Comment: If he wants, he can do

`std::string operator*(int i, std::string x) { std::string r; while( i-->0 ) r += x; return r; }    using namespace std::literals::string_literals;    int main() { std::cout << 3*" x"s; return 0; }`
(in c++14) and have it both ways :D

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no overload for `operator*` that allows operands of `int` and `const char [2]`

To put it simpler you could never multiply 4 by hello in reality so why allow it in c++

Answer (score 1):

As the error says there is no `operator *` defined for types `int` and `const char [2]` (`const char [2]` is the type of string literal  `" "`)

You could use class std::string for this operation. For example

`std::cout << std::string( 3, ' ' );`;

Or even you could use standard algorithm `std::fill_n`

For example

```
std::fill_n( std::ostream_iterator<char>( std::cout ), 3, ' ' );
```

There are many approaches to do the task.